# What is the critical value for those df not listed in Critical value table for Pearson correlation?

Tags: correlation, degrees-of-freedom

What is the critical value for pearson correlation df=190? The total number of samples is 192, so df is N-2 = 190. The tables have critical values for df 100, 150, 300, 500, 1000. If the df (N-2) falls in between (e.g. 145, 395, etc., which critical value should be considered to judge whether it is significant or not. Thanks.

Analyzed correlation between two variables, which have 192 observations in each. I could not find critical value for the df 190.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Karnan. We can't specifically answer this, because you don't state what the desired confidence level is nor which test you are using.  Do you know how to interpolate within tables?  Indeed, usually interpolation is not even needed because if, say, your correlation is large enough to be significant for a *smaller* sample size, then surely it's significant for your sample size, and so you can at least determine whether your result is significant.

Comment: I have interpolated the available values to get unknowns by following the commands given in [link](https://www.statology.org/linear-interpolation-in-r/)

Comment: Since you are using `R`, it makes no sense to interpolate in anybody's table -- `R` will calculate the value for you directly.